On the continuity a function given by evaluating compact subsets of continuous functions
Let $B$ be a closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and write $C(B)$ for the Banach space (with respect to the supremum norm) of the continuous real-valued functions on $B$.
Now given a compact subset $K$ of $C(B)$, define a non-negative function on $B$ via
$$F_K(x)=\mu(\mathrm{Ev}_x(K)), \quad x \in B,$$
where $\mathrm{Ev}_x: C(B) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the map that evaluates a function at the point $x \in B$ and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. (This function is well-defined since $\mathrm{Ev}_x$ is continuous and $\mathrm{Ev}_x(K) \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact.)
My questions: Is the function $F_K$ continuous? If not, is it at least Borel measurable? And does its set of discontinuities have Lebesgue measure 0?
My thoughts on this so far: First, by the Arzela-Ascoli theorem, the set $K$ is equicontinuous, so it looks plausible that as $x$ varies, the sets $\mathrm{Ev}_x$ should vary continuously in some sense. Now the pieces of the sets $\mathrm{Ev}_x$ that have non-zero Lebesgue measure probably consist of (unions) of closed intervals, so if somehow one is able to reduce the problem to considering closed intervals only, then the Lebesgue measure of these intervals should vary continuously, thus showing that $F_K$ is continuous.
Second, if $\mathcal{K}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the Hausdorff metric, then perhaps the equicontinuity of $K$ implies that the map $x \mapsto \mathrm{Ev}_x(K) \in \mathcal{K}(\mathbb{R})$ is continuous. Then, by a result in this article the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ is a Borel measurable function on $\mathcal{K}(\mathbb{R})$ and that would imply that $F_K$ is Borel measurable as well.

Here is a partial answer: The function is upper semicontinuous. Let $x\in B$ and assume that $\mu(\mathrm{Ev}_x(K))<r$. By outer regularity, there exists an open set $O\supseteq \mathrm{Ev}_x(K)$ with $\mu(O)<r$. The function $x\mapsto d(x,O^C)$ is continuous and has a strictly positive minimum $\epsilon$ on $\mathrm{Ev}_x(K)$. By the equicontinuity of $K$, we have for $\delta>0$ small enough that $\|x-y\|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ for all $f\in K$. Therefore, $\mathrm{Ev}_y(K)\subseteq O$ and $\mu(\mathrm{Ev}_y(K))<r$.
Aside: $\mathrm{Ev}_x(K)$ may contain no nontrivial interval even when it has positive measure, just take $K$ to be the set of constant functions whose value lies in some fat Cantor set. Each $\mathrm{Ev}_x(K)$ will be then equal to this set.

Thanks a lot. Meanwhile I think I managed to prove that the map $x \mapsto \mathrm{Ev}_x(K) \in \mathcal{K}(\mathbb{R})$ is indeed continuous with respect to the Hausdorff metric. (This gives another proof of the upper semicontinuity of $F_K$ since the Lebesgue measure is known to be upper semicontinuous with respect to the Hausdorff metric.) I'm curious, do you think this continuity property might help in proving that $F_K$ is continuous?

@S.Z. I think the function $x\mapsto\mathrm{Ev}_x(K)$ is can be represented by countably many pairs of continuous functions (I think at least pointwise equicontinuous) that describe continuously varying open intervals. But I wasn't able to use this to give either a positive or negative answer. It might make the problem easier, though.
